# Infinite loop in pow function

Tags: function, haskell, operator-precedence

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm getting an infinite loop here, but I don't know why.

```
module Main where

pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow x 0 = 1
pow x y = x * pow x y-1

main :: IO ()
main = print( pow 2 3 )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `x + pow x y-1` means `(x) + (pow x y) - (1)`, not `x + (pow x (y-1))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pow x y = x * pow x y-1
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It is parsed as

```
pow x y = (x) * (pow x y) - (1)
                ^^^^^^^^^
               infinite loop
```

Now you can see the infinite loop more clearly. You need to parenthesize `y-1`,

```
pow x y = x * pow x (y-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense =)

Comment: And sure not (+), but (*) =)))

Comment: @Lazyexpert Yes, but that wasn't the question :)